# limeJS looped animation doesn't display

Tags: javascript, html, limejs

I have a looped animation in LimeJS :

```
var scrollAnim = new lime.animation.MoveTo(800,248).setEasing(lime.animation.Easing.LINEAR);
var loopedAnim = lime.animation.Loop(scrollAnim);

roadSprite.runAction(loopedAnim);
```

However, when I use this code, nothing gets displayed on screen.

If I use the animation on its own:

```
var scrollAnim = new lime.animation.MoveTo(800,248).setEasing(lime.animation.Easing.LINEAR);
//var loopedAnim = lime.animation.Loop(scrollAnim);

roadSprite.runAction(scrollAnim);
```

It works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrrgh.... I feel silly.... 
I forgot to add

```
goog.require('lime.animation.Loop');
```

To the top of my js file.